# boost::interprocess::map insert gives: ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I'm trying to insert some values into a boost::interprocess::map stored in a shared memory.

The problem is that it gives me "ambiguous call to overloaded function" when I try to compile it and I'm not sure why. Here are some code snippets:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

typedef char * KeyType;
typedef long  ValueType;
typedef std::pair<const char *, long> Type_Value;

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<Type_Value, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::map<KeyType, ValueType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MyMap;


...

MyMap * myMap = segment.construct<MyMap>("CyValoresRTD")      //object name
                         (std::less<char *>() //first  ctor parameter
                         ,alloc_inst);     //second ctor parameter

...
char * text = "some text";
long value = 1234;
myMap->insert( std::make_pair(text, value) );
```

This insert call gives me some errors:

```
vcrtdserverimpl.cpp(445) : error C2668: 'boost::interprocess_container::map<Key,T,Pred,Alloc>::insert' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
with
[
        Key=VCRTDServer::KeyType,
        T=VCRTDServer::ValueType,
        Pred=std::less<VCRTDServer::KeyType>,
        Alloc=VCRTDServer::ShmemAllocator
]
p:\lib\boost_1_39_0\boost\interprocess\containers\container\map.hpp(407): could be 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> boost::interprocess_container::map<Key,T,Pred,Alloc>::insert(const std::pair<char *,long> &)'
with
[
        _Ty1=boost::interprocess_container::containers_detail::rbtree<VCRTDServer::KeyType ,std::pair<const VCRTDServer::KeyType ,VCRTDServer::ValueType>,boost::interprocess_container::containers_detail::select1st<std::pair<const VCRTDServer::KeyType ,VCRTDServer::ValueType>>,std::less<VCRTDServer::KeyType>,VCRTDServer::ShmemAllocator>::iterator,
        _Ty2=bool,
        Key=VCRTDServer::KeyType,
        T=VCRTDServer::ValueType,
        Pred=std::less<VCRTDServer::KeyType>,
        Alloc=VCRTDServer::ShmemAllocator
]
p:\lib\boost_1_39_0\boost\interprocess\containers\container\map.hpp(396): or       'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> boost::interprocess_container::map<Key,T,Pred,Alloc>::insert(const std::pair<const Key,T> &)'
with
[
        _Ty1=boost::interprocess_container::containers_detail::rbtree<VCRTDServer::KeyType ,std::pair<const VCRTDServer::KeyType ,VCRTDServer::ValueType>,boost::interprocess_container::containers_detail::select1st<std::pair<const VCRTDServer::KeyType ,VCRTDServer::ValueType>>,std::less<VCRTDServer::KeyType>,VCRTDServer::ShmemAllocator>::iterator,
        _Ty2=bool,
        Key=VCRTDServer::KeyType,
        T=VCRTDServer::ValueType,
        Pred=std::less<VCRTDServer::KeyType>,
        Alloc=VCRTDServer::ShmemAllocator
]
while trying to match the argument list '(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>)'
with
[
        _Ty1=char *,
        _Ty2=int
]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your problem, but the real `value_type` of a `map<char*, long>` is `pair<char* const, long>`, not `pair<char const*, long>`. I.e. your `Type_Value` typedef is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately this wasn't the problem. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you the problem.

```
could be ...
::insert(const std::pair<char *,long> &)'

or ....
::insert(const std::pair<const Key,T> &)'

 while trying to match the argument list '(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>)'
            with
            [
                    _Ty1=char *,
                    _Ty2=int
            ]
```

`std::map` keys are const, so are the pairs for inserting.  You probably would be better off  using  `std::string` as a key.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick! Using std::string resolved it.